# Physical Mailing Address Error - Marketing Cloud APIs

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm working with marketing cloud APIs to create Paste Email in the Content Builder. The Email is uploaded correctly, but when I try to send a test from MC, an error occurs:

> The email is missing a valid physical mailing address, which must be present on commercial emails per the federal CAN-SPAM Act. Please add a valid postal address in your account settings, or modify your email to include these fields, then you may resend your email.
>    - For HTML Paste emails, please select 'Physical Mailing Address' under 'Email Tools' to insert the physical mailing address in HTML version of the email.
>    - The recommended format for the physical mailing address in the TEXT version of your email is the following:
>    This email was sent by:
>    %%Member_Busname%%
>    %%Member_Addr%%
>    %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
>    - For Template based emails, your footer should already have the physical mailing address.

The code for the physical mailing address is entered in the HTML of the e-mail but is not converted by the Marketing Cloud. Moreover, if I upload and email manually it works correcly.

I'm using rest APIs.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the HTML Content is the same when you use the API and the manual import?

Answer (score 0):

This is standard error notification when you turn of the "prefilled" Salesforce MC Footer.

You can simply turn this error message of by creating an Support Ticket. Support will turn it off and you will be able to send out.

Comment: The author wants those fields to be displayed but says that the API option behaves different than the manual import. According how i understood it, the author wants to know the reason why the ampscript values are not being processed by the emailstudio when he uses emails that have been uploaded by api rather than totally ignoring them. I first thought the same way like you did (disabling physical email address from the backend from salesforce support) but i believe that the question aims into a different direction.

Comment: As written by Johannes, I would loike to understood why the ampscript values are not being processed by the emailstudio when I use emails that have been uploaded by API rather than totally ignoring them. I need this attributes have convert, because in commercial email they must be display. The HTML is the same for the manual upload. Can be a problem with my account permissions for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your API call has created the HTML version of the email correctly with the necessary Physical Address attributes.

I believe the problem is that the TEXT version of the email hasn't been created, therefore the TEXT version of the email has a blank Physical Address and you subsequently get the error.

When you create the email via the UI it will create a mocked up copy for the TEXT version. If you are creating he email via API then this TEXT version of the email hasn't been generated.

You will either need to create the TEXT version and add the physical address check there, or get the Physical Address check turned off (by support) in which case your HTML version will work - but you won't have a TEXT version of the MIME email.